# How to get rid of multiple overlapping shadows?

Tags: lighting, shadows

[image]

When I move around in the viewport, these shadows solidify as if they are one, but when I stop moving they look like this. How do i get it to be more like a single soft shadow?

Comment: Hello, are you in Cycles or in Eevee? If you are in Eevee, begin by going into the Render panel and under Sampling increase the Viewport value

Comment: I turned it up to 300 but the hard shadow edges remain. They're a bit softer but they're still there. Any other settings I could play around with?

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=kJMQadoD" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/kJMQadoD/)

Comment: it seems to work fine if you increase the sampling (you also need to increase the sampling for render before rendering), and also for the light enable the Contact Shadows option)

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the *Sampling* value, for Render as well:

[image]

Also select the light enable the *Contact Shadows* option, otherwise the object will look like it's floating:

[image]

Result:

[image]